# How to display a paperclip image in an email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, paperclip, actionmailer

I have a photo saved for a user.

I want to be able to send them an email and include their photo.

In the actionmailer email view I have

```
<%= image_tag @user.photo.url(:medium) %>
```

The photo's filename is included in the email as text.

How do I embed/show the actual photo?

Paperclip is used to add the photo and AWS S3 is used to store the photo.

The link looks almost correct except for a few numbers at the end

http://s3.amazonaws.com/applicantlabs/applications/photos/000/000/011/medium/breakingnews-img_2x-ipad.png?1431789984

and when I click on the link the page displays the following error

```
<Error>
<Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
<Message>
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
</Message>
<Bucket>applicantlabs</Bucket>
<Endpoint>applicantlabs.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
<RequestId>30457ECCCF09A</RequestId>
<HostId>
igkrUR0P/wes3aqpT7nAj2U7KXK91Qs+RBxwufjex15MPN5z1UCK8F2WSg6q0
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Does that code work on your website, if you don't send an email?

Comment: @MenelikTucker No, it displays a broken image link with the file's name... just like in the email

Comment: check the object to make sure the image is valid. sounds like it's not saving correctly or it cannot be displayed for some reason.

Comment: check the path in the broken image link and make sure the path is actually pointing to the image being saved, in your case it will be a url to your photo on aws.

Comment: I've added some extra details

Answer (score 0):

To use this Paperclip S3 setup my S3 bucket had to be of type "US Standard". As this was a new app with no images in the bucket, I just created a new "US Standard" S3 bucket.